# Load remote images efficiently using Glide

Tags: firebase-storage, android-glide

I am new to Glide and Firebase. Please help me with this silly problem. I am building an android app which has image gallery feature. These images are stored in Firebase storage and I want to use Glide to display them.

Firebase Storage has a cost for downloads and I want to minimize this cost. Is there a way to download these images locally for the first time and pass local storage path to Glide and if that fails, Glide should try to fetch image using remote url.

Answer (score 1):

Glide already has a cache that's used by default.  There's nothing you have to do to turn it on, and you can configure it.  I suggest reading the [documentation](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/caching.html).

Comment: Yes, I am aware about caching in Glide. But once cache is full, Glide will fetch image using remote url which will add up the download cost. Hence, I wish to download these images locally for the first time.

Comment: That's not exactly how it works.  When the cache gets too large, Glide will remove old items from the cache and add new ones as needed - this is called "cache eviction".  You can't have an infinitely sized cache - you have to accept that the cache can't possibly store everything you want, and that you eventually have to go back to the network to get items that are not in cache.

Comment: Doug, I understand your response fully. Due to the limitation on cache size, I want to keep images locally too. I reckon it will decrease network access to a great extent. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: If you want a permanent cache, you will have to write custom code for this.